# Update td value in HTML table using JavaScript getElementByID and addEventListener button click

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, getelementbyid, addeventlistener

So, I recently posted a question regarding a similar issues and it was resolved. I understood the solution. Now, I'm trying to expand on this with arrays and more code.

In the sample below, there is a table with one column having salary ranges and the other column will be counters for each individual that falls in that range.

The user on the page will enter a salary range, a calculation will be performed, and then I want the td value to update in the appropriate range. For some reason it is not working and I have absolutely no idea why. I've been stuck for hours, and I am new to JavaScript, so please bear with me. Thanks.

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var button = document.getElementById("submitButton");
        var salaryCount = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
        var enteredSalary = 0;

        window.addEventListener("load", start, false);

        function start() {
            button.addEventListener("click", buttonPressed, false);
        }

        function buttonPressed() {
            document.getElementById("salarySubmitted").value = "";
            enteredSalary = parseInt(document.getElementById("salarySubmitted"));
            var salary = calcWeeklySalary(enteredSalary);
            calcSalaryRange(salary);
        }

        function calcWeeklySalary(enteredSalary){
            var salary = 200 + (enteredSalary * .09);
            salary.toFixed(0);
            return salary;
        }
        /*
        function buttonClicked(){
            enteredSalary = parseInt(document.getElementById("salarySubmitted"));
            calcSalaryRange(enteredSalary);
        } */

        function calcSalaryRange(salesAmount) {
            if (salesAmount >= 1000) {
                salaryCount[8]++;
                document.getElementById("salaryCount9").value = salaryCount[8];
            }
            else if (salesAmount >= 900) {
                salaryCount[7]++;
                document.getElementById("salaryCount9").value = salaryCount[7];
            }
            else if (salesAmount >= 800) {
                salaryCount[6]++;
                document.getElementById("salaryCount9").value = salaryCount[6];
            }
            else if (salesAmount >= 700) {
                salaryCount[5]++;
                document.getElementById("salaryCount9").value = salaryCount[5];
            }
            else if (salesAmount >= 600) {
                salaryCount[4]++;
                document.getElementById("salaryCount9").value = salaryCount[4];
            }
            else if (salesAmount >= 500) {
                salaryCount[3]++;
                document.getElementById("salaryCount9").value = salaryCount[3];
            }
            else if (salesAmount >= 400) {
                salaryCount[2]++;
                document.getElementById("salaryCount9").value = salaryCount[2];
            }
            else if (salesAmount >= 300) {
                salaryCount[1]++;
                document.getElementById("salaryCount9").value = salaryCount[1];
            }
            else {
                salaryCount[0]++;
                document.getElementById("salaryCount9").value = salaryCount[0];
            }
        }
    </script>


    </head>

    <body>

    <h1>Salary Range Calculator</h1>
    Enter sales amount:
        <form>
            <input id="salarySubmitted" type="text" value="">
            <input id="submitButton" type="button" value="Submit">
        </form>
        Number of people who earned salaries in the following ranges:
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>$200-$299</td>
                    <td id="salaryCount0">0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$300-$399</td>
                    <td id="salaryCount1">0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$400-$499</td>
                    <td id="salaryCount2">0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$500-$599</td>
                    <td id="salaryCount3">0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$600-$699</td>
                    <td id="salaryCount4">0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$700-$799</td>
                    <td id="salaryCount5">0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$800-$899</td>
                    <td id="salaryCount6">0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$900-$999</td>
                    <td id="salaryCount7">0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$1000 and over</td>
                    <td id="salaryCount8">0</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You need to encapsulate your javascript code into "window.onload" function, in order to run the script only after the DOM has mounted.

Comment: Are you referring to using something like window.addEventListener("load", start, false); ? 

I have to encapsulate my entire code in this?

Comment: I mean..   
    <script>
      window.onload = function() {
        .... all javascript here...
     }
    </script>
    <body>....

Comment: @PabloDarde Thanks!